# Offline/local storage of data (text, images, …) in PhoneGap 3.5

Tags: cordova, local-storage, phonegap-plugins

I’m building a simple app using PhoneGap 3.5.0-0.20 and I’d like to store the app’s contents "offline" and locally on the device so the contents are not required to be downloaded each and every time.

While there seem to be thousands of ways to do it, I don’t get what’s the best way to do it in PhoneGap 3.5 using a JavaScript API. I know about `LocalStorage` but as far as I know, it has file size restrictions (5 MB) but I need to store round about 100 MB of content on the device. I need also a way to flush the cache as soon as I want to update it (= as soon as the device has an Internet connection).

I’d implement the check for updates and redownloading myself, I just need a way to store contents easily and persistent on the devices across platforms (iOS, Android, Windows Phone) and clear it.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: are the resource(text/images) static or dynamic in nature? I mean are they personalized for each user or will they remain the same for all the users? If they are static you can add the resources in the App itself.

Comment: The information is personalized for each and every user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `websql`. It's persistent, easy to use. But I will recommend any SQLite wrappers.

Check this out https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

This plugin is very easy to use, similar coding like `webSQL`

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
```